# Error trying to set my site up with Cloudflare

Tags: azure, cloudflare

I'm trying to add Cloudflare to my site - my site is a basic Azure site - it doesn't have a custom domain, (e.g. https://mysite20210708071234.azurewebsites.net/ - this is not the actual site).

I go to Cloudflare and add a new website, and I get the error:

```
mysite20210708071234.azurewebsites.net is not a registered domain
```

I've done a fair bit of googling, but all I can come up with is instructions to configure a custom domain - which I don't have.  My guess is that I need to configure something in Azure to allow Cloudflare to "see" the site - any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. You can use Cloudflare only on domains that you can control such as by owning a domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to do that. Cloudflare allows for registering root domains, you can't do that with a subdomain. However, you can buy some domain, register it on Cloudflare, point A/AAAA entries to a Azure site you have and change the webserver config to listen to this domain.

In that way you'd be able to use Cloudflare proxy for sure.